R terminal by vscode breaks to the next line with extra space. How do I fix it?
R terminal by vscode breaks to the next line with extra space. How do I fix it?

I wish the lines would break only after completing the whole horizontal space.

I don't know R very well, but does this answer your question? How do I tell summary to not wrap columns?
